# Amount of data read() syscall will actually read

Tags: c, linux, file

Suppose I have a file for which the file descriptor has more than n bytes left until EOF, and I invoke the read() syscall for n bytes. Is the function guaranteed to read n bytes into the buffer? Or can it read less?

Comment: Well, if your computer crashes... other cases might be signals occuring during the reading.

Comment: Even if the file holds more than `n` bytes, you must still check that `n` bytes were read. Make no assumptions about I/O in C: check everything.

Comment: **Why do you ask?**  I mean, in all the cases where one might wish to apply this knowledge, involve reasoning not mentioned in this question, that cause the answer to the underlying question, *"can I expect `read()` to return all the data I asked for, if the data exists"*, to be **No**. For example, in Linux, you should not assume that things you can read as if it was a file, is a file (because eventually someone wants to use your utility on a non-file anyway); and things like pipes and character devices definitely do not behave as files do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `read` system call is guaranteed to read as many many characters as you asked for, except when it can't.  But it turns out that there are so many exceptions -- so many cases where it can't read as many characters as you asked for -- that it basically ends up being safest to assume that any given `read` call probably won't read as many characters as you asked for.  I believe it's good practice to always write your code with that in mind.

The man page on my system says

> The system guarantees to read the number of bytes requested if the descriptor references a normal file that has that many bytes left before the end-of-file, but in no other case.

So if it's not a normal file, or if it is a normal file but there aren't enough characters, you'll get fewer than you asked for.  But in the case you asked about, yes, you should be guaranteed to get exactly as many characters as you asked for.

With that said, though, if you find yourself with a choice between assuming that `read` is allegedly guaranteed to read exactly the number of characters requested, versus acknowledging that it might return less, I would always write the code to assume it might return less.  That is, if you have a call like

```
r = read(fd, buf, n);
```

there isn't usually much to be gained by assuming that if `r` is greater than 0, it must be exactly `n`.  Your code has to be able to handle the `r < n` case so it will behave properly when it's almost at end-of-file, so unless you want to have two different code paths (one for "normal" reads, and one for the last read), you might as well write one piece of code, that can handle the `r < n` case, and let it operate all the time.

(Also, as Zan Lynx reminds in a comment, don't have the code notice that `r < n`, and infer from that that end-of-file is coming up soon.  Wait for `r == 0` before deciding you're at end-of-file.)

Comment: The `r < n` case handling can be buggy if the programmer assumes that's end of file. Only `r == 0` is end of file. Also that guarantee about `normal file` doesn't apply if it is a network filesystem, a FUSE filesystem, or some other process truncated or rewrote the file during your read call... yep, never assume.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thanks for the reminder; I meant to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

You could've read it from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) yourself:

> On Linux, `read()` (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
>          `0x7ffff000` (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes
>          actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
>          systems.)

So even if you had enough RAM and so on, you couldn't read a full-size DVD image in one go - however, this wouldn't be the sane thing to do either; to access such large files, `mmap` would be better.

---

Other than that, a signal might be delivered, which can cause exit with `EINTR` and buffer contents indeterminate.

> **ERRORS**
>
> [...]
>
> - `EINTR`            The call was interrupted by a signal before any data was read; see signal(7).

Comment: A signal handler without `SA_RESTART` set and a read call will interrupt but won't return `EINTR` if some data has been read. It will return the short read count.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the function guaranteed to read n bytes into the buffer? Or can it
> read less?

No, even if your file has more than `n` bytes before its end, the `read(fd, buf, n)` function is not guaranteed to read `n` bytes into bufffer and then return `n`. It can read less and return a positive value that is less than `n`.

See Linux man page at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of
> bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes
> are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
> end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a
> terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.